# How to reuse parts of slick query

Tags: scala, slick

edit: Note my project uses slick 2.0

I am writing couple of functions which looks like

```
def getByFooId(fooId: Long) : Option[(Foo, Bar, Option[Baz])] = {
   database.withSession { implicit session =>
     val query = for {
        ((foo, bar), baz) <- Foo.query join Bar.query on (_.id === _.fooId) leftJoin Baz.query on (_._1.id == _.fooId)
        if foo.id === fooId
     } yield (foo, bar, baz.?)
     query.list
  }
}

def getByBarId(bazId: Long) : List[(Foo, Bar, Option[Baz])] = {
   database.withSession { implicit session =>
     val query = for {
        ((foo, bar), baz) <- Foo.query join Bar.query on (_.id == _.fooId) leftJoin Baz.query on (_._1.id === _.fooId)
        if (bar.id === barId)
     } yield (foo, bar, baz.?)
     query.list
   }
}
```

These two functions are almost identical, the only difference is the if condition in the slick query building... I wonder how to refactor this code so that I can prevent duplication of slick code.

Comment: You are using old slick .... Use latest Slick ..

Comment: yes right now my project uses slick 2.0

Comment: Use SLick 3 .. slick 3 is much better than slick 2 .. in many ways